# Custom User-Agent not showing up in _SERVER variable

Tags: php, apache

In my Java app I am using a custom User-Agent in the http post message. The idea is to something a little different for one post message based on the User-Agent.

On the server side I am using PHP and turns out the $_SERVER array does not have the HTTP_USER_AGENT set. I can see it is set when I send a regular GET message from the browser to the php code. What's puzzling is the User-Agent is in fact getting set in my Java code and I can see it using tcpdump. After wasting a lot of time I figured out that the User-Agent is in fact sent correctly and I could get it using the apache_request_headers() function in my php code. Though it solves my problem I really want to understand what's going on. Did anyone else face this problem? Can someone explain why I am seeing this? I am new to PHP.

EDIT: Here is the User-Agent specific field copied and pasted from wireshark on the client side.

```
User-Agent: Android app1.0\r\n
```

Thanks,

P

Comment: Can you post your packet capture?  I suspect that the User-Agent actually isn't being set correctly.

Comment: @Brad - I would as soon as I go near my computer but why does apache_request_headers() show it?

Comment: @user220201, `apache_request_headers()` will show all request headers.  The value in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is actually the parsed version.  In other words, if the variable in `$_SERVER` isn't set, then your request header with the user agent wasn't parsed, meaning the name of your header probably has a typo.

Comment: @Brad - I pasted the User-Agent header captured using wireshark above.

Comment: @user220201, post the actual capture file.  Context matters.

Comment: @Brad - I know I don't have the whole thing, I am not at a computer and that was from a previous post about the same topic when I was still trying to figure things out.

Comment: The header you posted looks fine.  Come back when you can upload the capture file so we can take a look.